# How do use talend tLibraryLoad?

Tags: java, soap, talend

How do I use a jar in Talend? With tLibraryLoad one can load the Library but after that how do I use it or what other components do I need?

The jar I want to use is a complex API Client made for accessing a Java System via it'S SOAP API. Wich component is used for writing the calls to authenticate, retrieve data, ...? Where could I find a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've loaded a jar file, you can make references to methods from it in any of the custom Java code components (tJava, tJavaFlex, tJavaRow) or in a custom routine (under Code in the repository window to the left).

You can see examples and documentation for each component in the [online documentation](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide53EN/Home).
You need to register though (it's free).